# " Nothing to show " on android layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have problem with android studio which is i can't see source code folders on android layout as showen in screenshot below.

PS: i can see the folders on project layout.

[image: Nothing to show in android studio]

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the old android studio project folder(if any) under `%USERS%` of windows,refer to below image for more and re-sync the project, it will work smoothly

[image: Screenshot image]